# Sorting list of lists by two columns

Tags: python, mysql, list, sorting, nagios

I have a list of lists that were pulled from a MySQL query from nagios. I am trying to SORT by descending order in the 3rd column but also GROUP the 2nd column.

```
[['', 'All Events', 73], ['', 'check_asterisk_calls2-TEL', 1], ['pteln002', 'check_asterisk_calls2-TEL', 1], ['', 'check_asterisk_extension_error-TEL', 1], ['pteln004', 'check_asterisk_extension_error-TEL', 1], ['', 'check_es_snaps-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr005', 'check_es_snaps-UNX', 1], ['', 'check_exchange_mailqueue-WIN', 1], ['pexc001', 'check_exchange_mailqueue-WIN', 1], ['', 'check_health_measure-JVA', 2], ['pwspr031', 'check_health_measure-JVA', 1], ['pwspr049', 'check_health_measure-JVA', 1], ['', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 3], ['putpr002', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 1], ['putpr004', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 1], ['pwspr031', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 1], ['', 'check_jmx_HeapMemoryUsage_background-JVA', 1], ['putpr001', 'check_jmx_HeapMemoryUsage_background-JVA', 1], ['', 'check_localtouch-TEL', 1], ['pteln002', 'check_localtouch-TEL', 1], ['', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 12], ['psearchpr005', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr006', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr007', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr008', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln001', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln002', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln003', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln004', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln005', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln007', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln009', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln010', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['', 'check_tomcat-sem-UNX', 1], ['rwspr001', 'check_tomcat-sem-UNX', 1], ['', 'check_tomcat-UNX', 1], ['putpr002', 'check_tomcat-UNX', 1], ['', 'check_total_procs-UNX', 1], ['naggy2', 'check_total_procs-UNX', 1], ['', 'check_w305_KC_standby-DBA', 1], ['pdbdrkc01', 'check_w305_KC_standby-DBA', 1], ['', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 9], ['pfspr02', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['pmsvpr001', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr005', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr006', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr007', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['putpr001', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['putpr004', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['pwspr031', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['pwspr049', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['', 'disk-usage-UNX', 1], ['pmsvpr007', 'disk-usage-UNX', 1], ['', 'memory-usage-UNX', 25], ['p0crmpr001', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['p0crmpr002', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pmsvpr002', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pmsvpr008', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr013', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr014', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr019', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr022', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr024', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr025', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr026', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr027', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr030', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr031', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr032', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr033', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr036', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr041', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr042', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr043', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr044', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr045', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr046', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr049', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr050', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['', 'new_pending_phone-TEL', 1], ['pdbpr01', 'new_pending_phone-TEL', 1], ['', 'prod-consumer-rating-rewards-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-consumer-rating-rewards-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-credit-request-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-credit-request-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-ha-spd-update-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-ha-spd-update-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-payment-batch-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-payment-batch-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-session-log-loader-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-session-log-loader-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-sm-caldav-event-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-sm-caldav-event-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-sp-task-coverage-indexer-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-sp-task-coverage-indexer-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-watcher-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-watcher-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-ws-communication-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-ws-communication-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-ws-entity-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-ws-entity-JVA', 1]]
```

Here's an example of what I would like to output:

```
[['', 'All Events', 73], ['', 'memory-usage-UNX', 25], ['p0crmpr001', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['p0crmpr002', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pmsvpr002', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pmsvpr008', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr013', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr014', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr019', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr022', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr024', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr025', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr026', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr027', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr030', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr031', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr032', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr033', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr036', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr041', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr042', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr043', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr044', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr045', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr046', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr049', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['pwspr050', 'memory-usage-UNX', 1], ['', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 12], ['psearchpr005', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr006', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr007', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr008', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln001', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln002', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln003', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln004', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln005', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln007', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln009', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['pteln010', 'check_nfs_health-UNX', 1], ['', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 9], ['pfspr02', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['pmsvpr001', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr005', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr006', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['psearchpr007', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['putpr001', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['putpr004', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['pwspr031', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['pwspr049', 'CPU-Load-UNX', 1], ['', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 3], ['putpr002', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 1], ['putpr004', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 1], ['pwspr031', 'check_http_prod-JVA', 1], ['', 'check_health_measure-JVA', 2], ['pwspr031', 'check_health_measure-JVA', 1], ['pwspr049', 'check_health_measure-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-ws-entity-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-ws-entity-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-ws-communication-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-ws-communication-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-watcher-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-watcher-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-sp-task-coverage-indexer-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-sp-task-coverage-indexer-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-sm-caldav-event-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-sm-caldav-event-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-session-log-loader-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-session-log-loader-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-payment-batch-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-payment-batch-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-ha-spd-update-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-ha-spd-update-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-credit-request-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-credit-request-JVA', 1], ['', 'prod-consumer-rating-rewards-JVA', 1], ['Prod-MicroServices', 'prod-consumer-rating-rewards-JVA', 1], ['', 'new_pending_phone-TEL', 1], ['pdbpr01', 'new_pending_phone-TEL', 1]]
```

There are a few missing from the example because I had to do it by hand but the idea is all in there.

I thought I had the answer with the following but it's not even close.

```
weeklyreport = sorted(weeklyreport, key = lambda x: (x[2], x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you do it by modifying your sql query? I am pretty sure it would take less time especially for large data sets. As for your problem, you might want to take a look at [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function.

Comment: I had trouble with the mysql query too. I thought i would have better luck in Python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903637/mysql-order-by-category-and-subcategory No one seems to know how there either.